# Why indexer doesn't search Persian files?

Tags: java, indexing, encoding, lucene

I use lucene 3 for indexing some txt file like this.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String indexDir = "file input";
    String dataDir = "file input";
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    indexer indexer = new indexer(indexDir);
    int numIndexed, cnt;
    try {
        numIndexed = indexer.index(dataDir, new TextFilesFilter());

        cnt = indexer.getHitCount("mycontents", "شهردار");
        System.out.println("count of search in contents: " + cnt);
    } finally {
        indexer.close();
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Indexing " + numIndexed + " files took "
            + (end - start) + " milliseconds");

}
```

getHitCount function returns number of hits by an English word but by Persian word, it returns zero!

```
 public int getHitCount(String fieldName, String searchString)
        throws IOException, ParseException {

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);

    Term t = new Term(fieldName, searchString);
    Query query = new TermQuery(t);

    int hitCount = searcher.search(query, 1).totalHits;
    searcher.close();
    return hitCount;
}
```

How to set utf-8 in my project? I use netbeans and create a simple java project.
I just need a simple search in files!

It's my indexer class:

```
 private IndexWriter writer;
private Directory directory;

public indexer(String indexDir) throws IOException {
    directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));
    writer = new IndexWriter(directory,
            new StandardAnalyzer(
                    Version.LUCENE_30),
            true,
            IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    writer.close();
}

public int index(String dataDir, FileFilter filter)
        throws Exception {
    File[] files = new File(dataDir).listFiles();
    for (File f : files) {
        if (!f.isDirectory()
                && !f.isHidden()
                && f.exists()
                && f.canRead()
                && (filter == null || filter.accept(f))) {
            indexFile(f);
        }
    }
    return writer.numDocs();
}

private static class TextFilesFilter implements FileFilter {

    public boolean accept(File path) {
        return path.getName().toLowerCase()
                .endsWith(".txt");
    }
}

protected Document getDocument(File f) throws Exception {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("mycontents", new FileReader(f)));
    doc.add(new Field("filename", f.getName(),
            Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.add(new Field("fullpath", f.getCanonicalPath(),
            Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    return doc;
}

private void indexFile(File f) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Indexing " + f.getCanonicalPath());
    Document doc = getDocument(f);
    writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

Comment: could we see your indexer class? It seems to be something you implemented yourself

Comment: @Niklas I edited my question.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030329/lucene-encoding-java

Comment: @Niklas Thanks, I saw it but I don't know how to change my string for getHitCount function

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue isn't Lucene's encoding, per se, but the `FileReader`.  From the FileReader docs:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate.

The default character encoding is probably not appropriate, in this case.

Instead of:

```
doc.add(new Field("mycontents", new FileReader(f)));
```

try (assuming the file to be indexed is UTF-8 encoded):

```
doc.add(new Field("mycontents", new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF8")));
```